# How to get JSON objects properties when they are inside an array?

Tags: c#, json

I'm new at JSON and I'm learning so excuse me if I'm being ignorant. I have the following JSON:

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 373644788,
  "description": "something ",
  "start": "2016-04-28T02:23:01+02:00",
  "end": "2016-04-28T02:23:12+02:00",
  "updated": "2016-04-28T02:24:05+02:00",
  "dur": 11000,
  "user": "John Smith",
  "project": "First Project",

},
{
  "id": 373635064,
  "description": "None",
  "start": "2016-04-28T01:43:42+02:00",
  "end": "2016-04-28T01:44:06+02:00",
  "updated": "2016-04-28T01:44:21+02:00",
  "dur": 24000,
  "user": "Drake",
  "project": "Second Project",

}]
```

Each of these `JSON` objects, which are inside the array is a separate project and I need to extract the data (`ID, Name, Start, End`) from each one and put them into my `C# Class` and they should be stored separately for each project because they will be later exported into a database which has the same columns as these properties. 
I created the  `Class Definitions`:

```
 public class Definitions
    {
        public int id { get; }
        public string user { get; }
        public double dur { get; }
        public string project { get; }

        public override string ToString()
        {

              return  string.Format("ID: {0}, Name: {1}, Duration: {2}, Projekt: {3}", this.id, this.user, this.dur, this.project);


        }
```

The problem is that I can't access the properties inside my `JSON`.If I try to `Deserialize` it I get always `0` in my output on all my properties, as if I can't access these properties.

And the second question is how can I store them? I mean when they are exported to the database each of them should be automatically put into separate rows with each row having (`ID,Nama,Start,End`) columns.
Thank you.

Deserilize:

```
String jsonString  = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Json.json");
                Definitions def = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Definitions>(jsonString);
                Console.WriteLine(def);
```

Comment: Can you show us your Deserialization code???

Comment: That is my Deserialisation code. I put my JSON into local file. And I get 4 properties all with 0 value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your JSON has a property called `data` and this property is a array which holds many objects. What you need is to Deserialize from the root of the json, ie: from the data property.

You have already written your class with the same properties as in JSON this is right, what you want now is write another class for the `data` property.

```
public class DefinitionRoot 
{
    public List<Definitions> data {get; set;}
}
```

Now we have a class with a property called `data` and it holds list of our `Definitions`.

Now we can Deserialize as below.

`var allDefinitions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DefinitionsRoot>(yourJsonData);`

After this step, your `allDefinitons.data` will have list of your project details.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: I did that right now and I don't get an error but I get only a blank screen

Comment: Or I get this: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test2.Program+Definitions]. test2 is my namespace

Comment: You cannot write it in console... Place a debugger over their and look at the values, else you can also use watch window... Or else do this `Console.WriteLine(def[0].id);` you will get the ID of the first object in the array

Comment: Thanks that did it, in a watch window I see the values but how can I use them, for an example how can I write them to a file? And how can I export them into a database?

Comment: @user3613744 your `allDefinitions.data` will be a `List` type. So you can do a `foreach` loop on this and then access the values of each property using `.` property .. Since now inside the loop you are playing with each class ...